# Rails model callbacks triggered on wrong events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I have a model with the following callback registration:

```
after_save :set_initial_counts, on: :create
```

The [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) seems to say that the set_initial_counts method will be called after saving during the create chain, but not when saving during update. I have found, however, that it gets called after *every* save. How do I get it to only be called during create? (I considered the possibility that it was creating a new model that I hadn't intended for some reason, so I tried registering a test method to after_create. As you would expect, that doesn't get called.)

Updates to answer a few questions:
First, here is the text of set_initial_counts:

```
def set_initial_counts
  [tags, sources, characters].each do |coll|
    coll.each do |obj|
      obj.increment!(:stories_count)
    end
  end
end
```

The purpose of this is to manage a counter cache. The story object has_and_belongs_to_many tags, sources, and characters. Each of these has a stories_count column to store how many stories it's associated with.

Second: someone wanted to know why I'm not using after_create instead of after_save. In practice, I probably could use after_create, but I'd like to know why this isn't working, because the fact that it isn't working means that my understanding of callbacks is flawed, which could cause me to make more bugs in the future.

Thirdly: I'm aware that after_save is triggered during update. However, the third code block in [Section 2.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#callback-registration) indicates that I can use on: :create to ensure that set_initial_counts only gets called during create.

Comment: Please post the code in your `set_initial_counts` method

Comment: Why not just use `after_create`?

Comment: Guide clearly says that `after_save` will be triggered both after create and update. Read the texts with Red background after the section `3.3` in your mentioned link.

Comment: What is the method supposed to do? It soundslike something that should be done with column defaults or counter caches.

Comment: I've updated the original post to answer the first three comments. I didn't see max's comment, so I'll answer it here: you're correct that it should be done with a counter cache. However, at the time I started doing this, I wasn't aware that Rails had an automatic counter cache feature, so I wrote my own, and changing it now would require changing a lot of code, and isn't worth it.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12502).

The answer is basically that on is not an option to after_save, if you wanted to use the on create option, you'd just use after_create.